# what are multiple ways to display a div and an image next to each other and keep the same height responsively?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, object-fit

```css
.container {
  display: flex
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.videotext {
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
  align-text: center;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%
}

.image p {
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 2%;
  top: 25%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aYlD4AC.png">
    <p> asdf </p>
  </div>
  <div class="videotext">
    <p>Lorum ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please show me different examples or more efficient ways to display these two divs. Are there ways to do it without flex?

Also, I am trying to object-fit the image, but it doesn't seem to work...

Edit: I also forgot to add, how do I make them display on top of each other at a certain breakpoint?

Please see this example: https://codepen.io/zadro/pen/WJjRVd